# Adobe Edge: Get this symbol position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, adobe-edge

If I want to get the position of another symbol I know that this code works:

```
var left = sym.$("Rectangle").position().left;
```

But I want to get the `position().left` of a symbol I'm writing my code on and this doesn't work:

```
var left = sym.position().left;
```

Comment: what is the problem, elaborate..

Comment: Simply put: I want to get position of the symbol I'm currently writing the "mouseover" code on.

Comment: position().left is a jquery method, what is sym and does your first statement works

Comment: First statement works on other, referenced, symbols. But I can't get it to work on the symbol I'm writing the code on)

Comment: Like for example in ActionScript there is "this", to point to the object you're working with...

Comment: does sym represent any element in dom, only then you can calculate its position

Comment: Well, I thought sym represents current object, because of functions like sym.stop() and sym.play(). But it turns out it doesn't work for .position()

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the corresponding HTML element (div) of the symbol.

```
sym.getSymbolElement().position().left;
```

Explanation: When you do sym.$("Rectangle") you are targeting the element Rectangle inside the symbol, not the element symbol itself.